# how to downgrade apt packages to versions in archive?

Tags: debian, ubuntu, apt

I just noticed that the focal-proposed repository was included in my sources.list on ubuntu 20.04, although that [doesn't seem to be recommended](https://askubuntu.com/questions/401941/what-is-the-difference-between-security-updates-proposed-and-backports-in-etc). After disabling it, the command

```
apt-show-versions | grep newer
```

shows around 30 packages whose installed version is newer than the one in the repository. Is there a simple way to downgrade all of them to the available version?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I wrote a similar [answer here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/602540/272848)

To do this, first remove any lines with `focal-proposed` from `/etc/apt/sources.list` and `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*`.

Second we are going to tell apt to allow downgrades.  That means pinning `focal`, `focal-updates` and `focal-security` with priorities higher than 1000. Create `/etc/apt/preferences.d/focal` with this content:

```
Package: *
Pin: release n=focal
Pin-Priority: 1001

Package: *
Pin: release n=focal-updates
Pin-Priority: 1002

Package: *
Pin: release n=focal-security
Pin-Priority: 1003
```

If you don't use `focal-updates` or `focal-security` then skip those sections.

Third, run the following:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt dist-upgrade
sudo apt --fix-broken install
sudo apt autoremove
```

and keep rotating between those commands until everything is stable.

Finally, delete `/etc/apt/preferences.d/focal`.

---

Alternatively, you can just delete `focal-proposed`.  Those packages will eventually migrate to `focal-updates` when they pass their test and you'll be in sync again.

With your small delta, `--fix-broken install` and `autoremove` probably won't be neccessary but `apt` will tell you when you read the output of the previous commands.

---

To anyone else who comes accross this post:  [Downgrading is not supported](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/602497/272848). Any downgrade of significant size is likely to fail.  This is a pretty trivial case, but going from `focal` to `bionic` would probably be a disaster and leave you with a broken system.

Comment: Great, thanks! In the meantime I found a similar answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/257488/191408), but it uses "release o=*" in the pin. What's the difference? (Your explanation is better in any case)

Comment: [`man apt_preferences`](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/apt/apt_preferences.5.en.html) describes `o=` as the "originator of the packages in the directory tree of the Release file".  I don't honestly know what that means other than the given example is `Debian`.  `n=` is the codename (`bullseye`, `bionic`, or `focal-updates`). `a=` is the suite (`stable`, `unstable`, `testing`)

Comment: I found an example in the man page where: `Pin: release o=Debian Pin-Priority: -10` will uninstall any packages which are not Debian-originated.

Comment: The `release o=*` constraint means "not locally installed", that is, packages which have a known origin. If your sources contain only the repos from which you want package version installed, it's a shorter than spelling out specific names.

Comment: Wow, that is an elegant way to do it

Answer (score 1):

Little bit shorter.

```
cat /etc/apt/preferences.d/focal.pref 
Package: *
Pin: release n=focal
 
Pin-Priority: 1001
```

The record assigns a high priority to all package versions belonging to any distribution whose Codename is "focal".

Note works only when focal-proposed is no longer active.